# Arrange 9 circular divs into a christmas tree shape

Tags: html

Using Notepad++ and HTML I would like to arrange the divs with the text:name into a 2,3,4 triangular shape with the gold div on top. Here is my code so far, I don't know how to arrange them in this format:
    
    
        
    
    
    Family Tree

```
<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid; margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
<p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
<p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
<p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
<p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
<p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
<p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
<p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 450px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
<p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
<p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 2,3,4 does not sound like christmas tree to me... Could you specify a little bit more what kind of tree?

Comment: It will be more of a triangle with the gold circle on top, and then the rest of the divs under it in a 2,3,4.

Comment: so in all 4 different lines under each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a masterpiece of code by any means but seems to work

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div style='width: 100%; text-align: center'>

    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid; margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center; background-color:gold">
    <p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
    </div><br />

    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
    <p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
    <p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
    </div><br />

    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
    <p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
    <p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
    <p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
    </div><br />

    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
    <p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
    <p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
    <p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;height: 150px;width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;border: 2px solid black;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;">
    <p style="position: relative;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 25px;">name</p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```